# How use Wire with Flow in client gRPC?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, square-wire, grpc-kotlin

i need stream of a service gRPC with Wire and need use Flow on client, but `executeBlocking()` do not provide method with return via Flow, need implementation manual via `flow` emits?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna use `execute`, instead of `executeBlocking()` and find some way to transform the `Channels` into `Flows`? Or just start a new Flow from the blockingGet value?

```
flow {
  emit(value)
}
```